# Running .exe files in Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, exe

I am a **Mac user** who wants to run a few **.exe files** from my Java process using Process and Runtime classes.

I know that it is **not possible** to execute .exe files in general in **Mac OS X**.

Is there a Mac application which can wrap these .exe files so that they can be executed ? 
Does Apple provide anything by itself ?

The alternative I am using now is to run the Java process in Windows. Yet, it is cumbersome in general.

Comment: Completely pointless bitching: I loath the usage ".exe file" in place of "Windows executable". We now return you to your regularly scheduled question and answer site.

Comment: lol, i ve learnt to accept that there are other people in the world that are not technical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Darwine](http://darwine.sourceforge.net/)

Edit: I should probably point out that this is not a 100% solution. Virtualized Windows will nearly always work better, through Parallels or some similar virtualization software. But Darwine is free and runs most Windows software acceptably.

Answer (score 4):

Besides wine you can get [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)(free), [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/)($$$) or [VMWare](https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/)($$$).

Comment: true, except it would be very hard for the java process to interact with those.

Comment: all can be set up to run exe file automatically.  so a java process should be able to start them up fine.

Comment: there is more to interacting than "starting"

Comment: If the program is written in java... why isn't there a mac version?

Answer (score 4):

Well, if it's a .NET application then you can possibly run it with Mono, but I'm betting it's a native binary and you'll have to use something like the aforementioned Wine. I thought it was really cool the first time I ran a .exe using Mono on OSX, it just felt wrong, so I had to share.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it exists, but you would need something like wine for OSX. The reason why is that the .exe would nearly certainly use OS specific system calls and library functions.

**EDIT:** looks like it [does exist](http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX)

Answer (score 0):

java -jar file.exe and monofile.exe both works natively on MACOS with native MACOS java and mono

Answer (score 0):

1)Install Wine and Winebottler from http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/

2)You may have to change the System Preferences >Security & Privacy>Allow Apps downloaded from>Anywhere

2)Click the xyz.exe and select winebottler for running application